# jQuery parse string to get first <td> tag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have the following string:

```
<td class="internal-first-row add-internal-hover cursor">Fname Lname</td>
<td class="center add-internal-hover cursor">Campaign Manager</td>
<td class="center classval add-internal-hover cursor">
    <input id="h_user_id_147" value="147" type="hidden">
    <a id="delete-internal-user-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">X</a>
</td>
```

In jQuery, how can I get the html() only of the 1st `<td>` tag which is "Fname Lname"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code

```
var value = $('td:first').html()
console.log(value)
```

to be more precise and for performance reasons, find within your table

```
var value = $('#table_id').find('td:first').html();

or 

var value = $('#table_id').find('td').first().html();
```

btw.. your td elements should be within tr elements :) to make it as correct html markup.

If that is a plain string, you can get the value using

```
var value = $('<table>')append(
                '<tr>'+your_html_string+'</tr>'
            ).find('td:first').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("td:first").html()
```

Use the first selector

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
$("td:first").html();
```

or

```
$('td').first().html();
```

or

```
$(".havingClassName  table tbody tr td:first-child").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('.yourtableclass tr').each(function(){
 var text = $('td:first-child',this).html());  
});
```